# Winedt vs TeX Editors on MacOS

Tags: texstudio, editors, winedt

I spent years on Win using Winedt as TeX/LaTeX editor. Very good, well worth the money.

Now I decided to move to an iMac and MacOS, of course. I have TeX installed (MiKTeX, for different reasons) and I use (for now) TeXStudio as TeX/LaTeX editor and it's basically OK. On MacOS WinEdt is NOT an option since there is no version for this OS.

I have a problem, though.

With WinEdt if I chose in document settings "ASCII" (see picture below....

[image: Image from control panel of WinEdt]

and line wrap at 90 (say), I could write a paragraph like

[image: Paragraph using WinEdt]

Notice that each line is numbered (I have Hard Returns, it seems). Indeed I want to have this, because it is better for using Git or some other Version Control System.

Next, if I decided to insert some ADDITIONAL text in a previous line I would get "automatic reflow", as you can see here below (look at the XXXXXX characters)

[image: Text Reflow]

As you can see I do NOT get "broken lines" (I know TeX doesn't care but this is not the issue). And this is good for me.

If I try to do the same with TexStudio I get broken lines. Either I use soft returns (not good in my opinion...)  or I get lines broken at the point where hard returns were inserted in the source file when I first wrote my text. I know how to reformat the paragraph through some maneuver in TexStudio but what bothers me is that WinEdt seems to be able to do this "automatically" without any "manual fix" by me each time I insert text and want to have a nice text reflow in a paragraph.

Assuming that I did explain my problem well enough, I would like to know if there is a way to have TexStudio behave as WinEdt or, for that matter, if there are editors on MacOS (even not free, I'm happy yo pay for good software) which are well suited for LaTeX and behave as well as WinEdt, which for me is great. I know there are people who keep a Win partition on their Mac just for using WinEdt but I do not want to come to that...

Thanks
Maurizio

Comment: Have you considered MacTeX with its TeXShop editor?

Comment: Thanks. I know about it. Do you know if TeXShop would behave as I would like? Maurizio

Comment: TeXShop *will* automatically reflow text to fit the current window width. And if you change the window width, TeXShop will also reflow text then. You just don't have to think through the (to me) confusing array of kinds of returns that WinEdt uses; on the TeXShop Settings > Editor panel, leave the Wrap Lines setting to its default "by Word." (If you really want, you can select, instead, "None" or "by Character". For many years while still in the Windows world I used WinEdt and always found it confusing and complicated to configure; I find TeXShop much more straightforward to configure.

Comment: Thanks! (I see you are a retired mathematician, as I am....) I can download and try TeXShop, of course. But what is not clear to me is wether the behavior you describe is due to TeXShop just using soft returns, or not. Maurizio

Comment: If you're going to try try TexShop, you may want to install the whole MacTeX, which uses TeXLive instead of MikTeX.